# Why does str.format throw a KeyError: ' ' for this seemingly straightforward string formatting operation?

Tags: python, format

I wrote the code below and I am getting an error message wherever I used the ".format()" method compared to the f-string lateral. Error message is:

KeyError: ' '

Not sure why the ".format()" is not working like he f-string lateral. If not, the code is running just fine excpet in areas where ".format" was used

Can you please point me in the right direction? Much appreciated!

```
class Inventory ():

    make = "Verra"

    def __init__ (self,country,isnew,sbalance = 0,cbalance = 0):

        self.country = country
        self.isnew = isnew
        self.cbalance = cbalance
        self.sbalance = sbalance



    def entry_sugar (self,sugar_1 = 0):

        self.sbalance += sugar_1

        print(f"You have just added {sugar_1} bags of sugar to your sugar 
        inventory")

        print(f"Your new sugar inventory balance is : {self.sbalance} bags.")



    def entry_corn (self,corn_1 = 0):

        self.cbalance += corn_1

        print(f"You have just added {corn_1} corn(s) to your corn inventory.")

        print(f"Your new corn inventory balance is : {self.cbalance}.")




    def withdawal_sugar(self,sugar_2 = 0):

        if self.sbalance == 0:

            print("Your current sugar inventory is at 0.You cannot withdraw an 
            item at this time")

        else:

            self.sbalance = self.sbalance - sugar_2

            print("You have just withdrawned { } bags of sugar from your sugar 
            inventory".format(sugar_2))

            print(f"Your new sugar inventory balance is : {self.sbalance} bags 
            of sugar.")



    def withdawal_corn(self,corn_2 = 0):

        if self.cbalance == 0:

            print("Your current corn inventory is at 0.You cannot withdraw an 
            item at this time")

        else:

            self.cbalance = self.cbalance - corn_2

            print(f"You have just withdrawned {corn_2} corn(s) from your corn 
            inventory")

            print(f"Your new corn inventory balance is : {self.cbalance}")


    def total_balance (self):

        print("Balance Summary:")     
        print("Your corn balance is {}".format(self.cbalance))
        print("Your sugar balance at this time is{}".format(self.sbalance))
```

Comment: Remove the space between your curly braces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely a typo arising because of the spaces you've added in your curly braces. However, I think it's worth explaining a little bit about why this happens so you're careful not to make the same mistake.

According to the docs in [`.format`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.format),

> The string on which this method
>   is called can contain literal text or replacement fields delimited by
>   braces {}. Each replacement field contains either the numeric index of
>   a positional argument, or the name of a keyword argument.

What this means is that anything inside a curly brace `{}` will be interpreted as a replacement field. In this case, it's the space.

To see how this'd work, you'd have to do something bizarre such as passing kwargs to `format`:

```
>>> '{ }'.format(123)
KeyError: ' '
>>> '{ }'.format(**{' ': 123})
'123'
```

This would've been very straightforward literal interpolation had you just omitted the space.

```
>>> '{}'.format(123)
'123'
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the extra insight. Truly helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Extra space in-between `{ }` is the problem.

```py
value = 123

print("{}".format(value))  # '123'

print("{ }".format(value))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: ' '
```

In [Formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-498-formatted-string-literals), you can add extra space in `{ }` if you need.

```py
value = 123

print(f"{value}")  # 123

print(f"{ value }")  # 123
```